# Find out which app/service is changing my input volume

Tags: audio, bluetooth, mac-mini, headphones, sound-volume

I'm having a persistent issue where my system-wide input volume is being changed while I'm talking. This is happening regardless of which app I'm on. When I have the system settings open while I'm talking, I can see the input volume slowly dropping (and sometimes rising) in irregular intervals until it reaches zero and the headset is muted. I have the suspicion it's related to the headset (Microsoft Modern Wireless Headset), as I didn't have any problems with a previous wired headset, though that was a while ago.

I've already disabled the automatic volume control in a lot of apps (Slack, Microsoft Teams, Zoom …) and I'm running out of ideas. How can I find out which app, driver or service is changing my input volume?

Mac mini 2018, macOS 13.4.1 (c)